# Python requests module gets stuck on requests.get() and gets timed out

Tags: python, web-scraping, get, python-requests-html

I've been trying to web scrape from the following site: "https://www.india.ford.com/cars/aspire/"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

response = requests.get("https://www.india.ford.com/cars/aspire/", timeout=5)

if response.status_code!=200:
    print("error!")
else:
    print(response.status_code)
```

The execution gets stuck indefinitely.

On using `timeout=5`

I get the following error:

[image]

I'm new to this so sorry if this is a noob question. Any help is highly appreciated! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeout need to use try except.

This page needs to disguise the browser.

```py
try:
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
    }
    response = requests.get("https://www.india.ford.com/cars/aspire/", headers=headers, timeout=5)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("error!")
    else:
        print(response.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as error:
    print('time out')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand, that I need a try, except block. However, the problem is occuring at requests.get(). Execution does not progress any further after reaching it.

Comment: Thats is due to authentication error. If you try `curl https://www.india.ford.com/cars/aspire/` it will give you access denied error. Try get request with a different url like- `https://api.github.com` and you shall understand the issue.

Comment: Need to disguise the browser, I have updated the answer, you can try and see.